# Configuring Impersonation for Azure Function Running in an On-Prem Windows Container

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, windows-container

I'm running a hello world azure function app with an HTTP trigger in a windows container on-prem (yay!).

The question I have now is is it possible to impersonate the user initiating a request from the HTTP trigger? The goal is to allow the function to talk to our in-house authorization system and get back an authorization token.

Could it be just a matter of changing the authorization level to something like Authorization.User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. We send identity info to the Http Trigger, it talks to authorization backend and brings back a token to the trigger, we get the token as a response of the Http trigger.

Since it's an in-house authorization system we can't rely on the [authorization level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#authorization-keys) of Http trigger. It is used for Functions deployed in Azure site, where we need to provide a corresponding key to access Http trigger secured by different auth level.

BTW, the auth level should always be anonymous(e.g `AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous` in c#) if we work with Http trigger in on-prem container. Because locally we don't have any key to access the trigger secured by level other than anonymous.

Comment: Just so I understand... the trigger would make a call to the api of the in-house auth system, get the token response, and do whatever work it needed to do from there?

Comment: @AspiringDevOpsGuru True, note that we'd better not put some long-time running job before sending response back in http trigger.